# How to parse a string by words

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a string by highlighting all wards. At now I figured out how to split words with any symbols. But how to rewrite the code to discard words with numbers or any other characters? Here is my code:

```
String s = "AaA    bbd   cDef   d1s    s/4    +xx_x     asdgag    34545rtrtr.";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s.split(p.pattern())));
```

Not valid words: 
*“d1s”, “s/4”, “+xx_x”, “34545rtrtr.”*

Appropriate words: 
*“AaA”, “bbd”, “cDef”, “asdgag”*

Comment: Use another pattern. Read up on them.

Comment: Overkill: compile pattern, get the original string back :P

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
"\\b[A-Za-z]+\\b"
```

Where,

- `\b` marks a word boundary.
- `[A-Za-z]` means every letter, upper or lower case
- `+` means "one or more".

Comment: You don't have to split on it, search for matches instead.

Comment: @Alex "Your solution doesn't work properly." No, your implementation is wrong.